# Determining a basis for Col($A$) and a dimension for the null space of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&0&-2&1\\1&-1&1&1&0&0\\-1&1&-1&2&5&-1\end{bmatrix}$
>
> a) Determine a basis for Col($A$)
>
> b) What is the dimension of the null space of $A$?

I just want to make sure I am not doing this incorrectly.

part a) I put $A$ in rref form to get: $rref(A) = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&0&-2&1\\0&0&0&1&2&-1\\0&0&0&0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ so I got the basis for Col(A) = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$

Then for part b)

I know that nullity($A$) = # of non-pivot columns (or free vars) so I got that dim(null(A)) = 4? Since i have 4 free variables?

Comment: You haven’t quite finished row-reducing $A$, but even at this stage you should be able to tell that its column space is three-dimensional, not two-dimensional. Knowing that should make it really easy to find a basis for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix can be reduced with the following steps

- add $-1$ times row 1 to row 2
- add $1$ times row 1 to row 3
- add $-2$ times row 2 to row 3
- scale row 3 by $-1$
- add $2$ times row 3 to row 1
- add $-2$ times row 3 to row 2

This gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2
\end{array}\right]
$$
Columns one, four, and five are the pivot columns. Hence
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Col}{Col}\Col A=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\left\{
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
1 \\
2
\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-2 \\
0 \\
5
\end{array}\right]
\right\}
$$
To get a feel for what $\Col A$ looks like, you can put these basis vectors into the rows of a matrix
$$
C=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
-2 & 0 & 5
\end{array}\right]
$$
The rows of $\rref C$ also form a basis for $\Col A$. Here,
$$
\rref C=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence
$$
\Col A=\Span\left\{
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
\right\}=\Bbb R^3
$$

So $\dim\Col A=3$ and the rank-nullity theorem implies that 
$$
\dim\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null A=\#\text{ columns of }A-\dim\Col A=6-3=3
$$

Comment: Since the column space turns out to be good old $\mathbb R^3$, why not just use its standard basis?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Seems pedagogically incorrect, no? Listing the columns corresponding to the pivot columns works in general.

Comment: What seems pedagogically incorrect to me is to try to hide the (pretty important) fact that the column space is the entire $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm One could equally say that just using the standard basis would hide the fact that the columns corresponding to the pivot columns give a basis for the column space in the general case. Either way I've updated the answer to make it clear that the column space of this matrix is indeed all of $\Bbb R^3$.